# How to create a full pattern matrix?

Tags: r

Say I would create the 8 patterns of 0/1 with 3 cases:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

Is there a simple function in R to do that for `n` cases?

Comment: `expand.grid(0:1,0:1,0:1)` ?

Comment: Thanks, Josh. It's helpful! BTW, how to index `n` to generalize it?

Comment: `do.call(expand.grid, replicate(n, 0:1, simplify=FALSE))`

Comment: I think you want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23811103/expand-grid-with-unknown-dimension-in-r/23811211#23811211) -- just what baptiste was typing up as I typed this. If you agree, I'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Should I delete my question or better to mark as duplicate here?

Comment: I'll just close it as a dup, since in theory that'll make it more likely that future users will be able to find these answers by searching the internets for them. Cheers.